# AngularJs: round scope variable attached to input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, rounding

I'm trying to round a $scope-variable attached to an input-form - but just in the view!

Normally, if you want to round a number in your view you do it like this:

```
{{ price | number: 2 }}
```

What if I want to round the variable but need the unrounded value to insert it into the database? If I use a filter it wont work this way.

I use a function to increase/decrease the price by percentage so is there a way to just round the scope, attached to an input-form, in the view like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="price|number: 2"/>
```

Comment: When are you expecting the number to be rounded in the textbox? On focus out of the textbox or as the user is typing?

Comment: I know I've had the inverse issue:angular would update only the scope and not the actual model.It was because of my data structure:{object1{"name":"blabla"},object2{"name":"bla2"}} -> I had to change it {prop:"blabla",prop2:"bla2"}

Comment: @WayneEllery Good question. I think the number should be rounded when the price is loaded from the service and the user hits the increasePrice-Button which will add like 5% to the price.

Comment: So can't you just use the javascript `round()` function when the increase/decrease are clicked.

Comment: Won't this overwrite the actual - unrounded - price? for example the price is set 12.5 and I want to increase it for 5%. then i'll go for something like   price = round(price + 5%, 2). But if I want to insert the price in to the database the actual price will be round(price + 5%, 2) and not (price + 5%)  - which I actually need

Comment: So what value you want to save when the user changes the value?

Comment: Well the user has to click the save-Button to save the unrounded price variable